# Difference between methods to getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, class, resources, classloader

Can somebody tell me what's the difference between `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("TestFile.txt")` and `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("TestFile.txt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are (more or less) equivalent. `Class#getResourceAsStream()` will get the `ClassLoader` internally and delegate the `getResourceAsStream` call to it.

Thanks to [VGR's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394132/difference-between-methods-to-getresourceasstream/24394172?noredirect=1#comment37781832_24394172). It's important to note that `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)` first delegates to `Class#getResource(String)` which, if it doesn't start with a `/`, transforms the `String` argument passed by pre-pending the package name of the corresponding class with a `/` replacing each `.`.

Comment: It probably should be mentioned that the two calls in Vwin's question are not identical.  To make them function identically, either the second must pass `"/TestFile.txt"` or the first must pass `MyClass.class.getPackage().getName().replace('.', '/') + "/TestFile.txt"`.